Prisma: How to detect pending database migrations in development environment?
Problem
I am working on a T3 stack application now: a Next.JS app, Prisma ORM, Typescript, the works. Often as I'm pulling fresh changes made by my co-workers, these changes include database migrations.
The application code relies on the new state of the database, but the migrations haven't been applied to my development database. So the application starts failing in a million weird ways. I go on a debugging journey that doesn't make any sense until suddenly I remember, 'Check migrations'. This is often the culprit, and a lot of time is wasted for nothing.
Desired Outcome
I want the application to crash and burn with a very explicit message. I have done a lot of Ruby on Rails development in the past, and it's famous for the default behaviour of crashing in development when there are pending migrations

As far as I know, there is nothing built-in that I can use for that, so I want to build some guardrails for myself and my team.

On startup I want to crash the application server (in development) if there are pending migrations.
When the dev server is already running, I want the HTTP requests to fail, and the application to render something helpful (see RoR example above). This is important because in practice we rely on hot reload a lot, and it's likely that a developer will not restart the dev server too often.

Bits and pieces

How do I programmatically get the status of migrations with Prisma? Something equivalent to prisma migrate status command, but in the application code? Couldn't find anything in the Prisma Client docs.
Once I find a way to do this, what would be the implications of adding this check in a middleware on every inbound HTTP request?
Is there a different way to deal with this problem that I'm not seeing because of my previous biases?


Why not stop the dev server from starting at all? To me, this seems more straightforward than starting the server only to have it crash or return an error for all requests.
Just like you suggested, prisma migrate status can be leveraged to detect pending migrations. If there are some, the command will report something like:
3 migrations found in prisma/migrations
Following migration have not yet been applied:
20240424065014_migration_name_here

If there are NOT, the result will instead be:
3 migrations found in prisma/migrations

Database schema is up to date!

We can look for the "schema is up to date" string and only start the dev server if it is found.  You can do this with an npm script. Let's say you usually start your dev server with this script:
"start:dev": "node dist/index.js"
We could do for example:
"start:dev": "prisma migrate status | grep -qi \"schema is up to date\" && node dist/index.js"||echo \"Please run DB migrations!\"
What this does is:

run migrate status
pipe result to grep, use quiet (-q) and case-insensitive (-i) mode
if schema is up to date, start the server...
...or if not, echo a reminder to run pending migrations

A caveat: this relies on prisma migrate status returning a message in certain format; though, if this message ever changes, you should quickly notice it as your dev server will fail to start.

Thank you for the suggestion! I would prefer to find a way to do this in-applciation because of the point 2 from Bits and Pieces section — ultimately I want to find a way to catch the schema version mismatch and signal the developer to run the migrations. While the dev server is running (like a ROR application would in development)
But adjusting the script is a good stop-gap measure, thank you for the idea!
